# Intent filter for custom URLs not working in GMail

Tags: android, gmail

I set up my app to open certain patterns of URLs - e.g. here's `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation">

            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="mywebsite.com"
                    android:pathPattern="/somedir/.*"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This works fine when opening links from a browser, Google Keep, etc.

However, the **GMail app seems to ignore this** - when opening up a link in an email message, it just opens it up in its built-in mini browser. The only way it works in GMail, is if I long-press the link, choose `Open in Browser`, and then the browser detects my custom intent-filter.

Is there a way around this? Whether it's changing `AndroidManifest.xml` somehow, or changing the HTML/JS code of the link in the email.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code and you won't be able to change it - offending apps (like Gmail, Facebook, Messenger etc.) don't even query package manager to match activities for target url - they just feed that link straight to a `WebView` inside their app.

This is an issue of some wicked design, thinking that behavior is quicker and more desirable than using regular web browser.

Only way out is scouring thru that apps settings and disabling internal browser since it seems to always be enabled by default.

Comment: That's a bummer - and there is no way to enforce opening the link in an external browser via HTML? (e.g. <a href="..." target="_blank">)